# htaccess redirect of URL's containing query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, litespeed

I have one URL, **domain.com/fun/page/** which i want to redirect to itself when query string is appended to it (**domain.com/fun/page/?xyz**).

Server is LiteSpeed and no matter what (*I've tried numerous rules found here and elsewhere on the web*), I don't get what I want. Seems I'm just not skilled in writing matching regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `/fun/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fun/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^page/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,R=302,L]
```

Trailing `?` will strip off any existing query string.

Comment: I don't have access to site document root, I just have FTP access to /fun directory. Would rewrite rule differ if I put .htaccess in it ?